# javascript.Jquery:: based on the selected value alert the value from map

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I am passing a hashmap from my controller to view
and i am accessing it fron javascript/jQuery

```
alert("${result}")
```

which prints

```
{
   hus=[hus@gmail.com,SE,9902766542],
   vin = [vin@gmail.com, SE,887654433]
 }
```

i have a select dropdown tag in my doument.

```
 <select name="name" onchange="alertDtailsof(this.value);">

    <option value="hus">hus</option>

    <option value="hus">vin</option>
```

now lets say i have selected "hus" from option 
in my `alertDtailsof()`  function i need to alert related field of `hus` from ${result}

```
  function alertDtailsof(selectedval){
     here if selected value is "hus"
     then from ${result} , it should alert hus@gmail.com,SE,9902766542, these 3 values
  }
```

Comment: the result is not a valid object, it should be `{
   hus:[hus@gmail.com,SE,9902766542],
   vin : [vin@gmail.com, SE,887654433]
 }`

Comment: ya.. when i am printing from my controller it is valid , but when i do alert from javascript it gives differenty  like this

{
   hus=[hus@gmail.com,SE,9902766542],
   vin = [vin@gmail.com, SE,887654433]
 }

Answer (score 0):

You have a to refer to the `result` variable. In addition, you have to correct the values for the different elements in your select element. Right now both options have the same value name.

Supposing that the variable result is accessible in the context of alertDtailsof, you'd have the following:

```
function alertDtailsof(selectedval){
    console.log(result[selectedval]);
}
```

If you don't want to change the values in the options, then you're going to have to find the selected item's text.

Here's a Fiddle if you **don't** change the value attribute according to the text: http://jsfiddle.net/6CxYR/1/ .

Answer (score 0):

This works if `${result}` in fact does yield a hashmap object:

```
var people = ${result};

function alertDtailsof(selectedval){
    alert(people[selectedval]);
}
```

Here is a working JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QfJNN/2/